# Why using display:block for block level elements

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I see designers using `display: block` for block level elements? For instance I saw people using `display:block` on elements that are already block level elements like `ul, li` and headers like `h1, h2, h3` and so on.

If browsers already treats those elements as block level elements why do I have to use display block on them ?

thanks in advance

Comment: where did you see people put that there?

Comment: Could be an override for some other CSS, could be for just batching elements and ensuring they're `display: block` for safe measure - `<li>`'s aren't inherently 'display:block;`

Comment: Can the peeps voting to close please comment? I'm not sure how this is unclear or opinion based? Yes, there can be many answers as to why this is done but that doesn't make it a bad question. In fact, a question like this and answers to it can be a great resource to others befuddled by the same situation.

Comment: @PaulSasik - The problem is that SO deals in objective answers. There's simply no way of knowing why unspecified designers have done such a thing. Any answers can only be speculation.

Comment: @Alohci: Rephrase the question for yourself thusly: "What are the situations when working with HTML when the display:block; attribute would be useful?" Does that sound like a question that would only lead to speculation? I don't think so and that is basically what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers recognize `h1`, `h2`, `ul` correctely (they were always included in HTML) but for newer HTML5 elements like `header`, `footer` and `main` and `canvas` it's a good practice. Because older browsers didn't recognize them, but if you did declare them as `block` element they will display them properly.

For instance IE8 wouldn't recognize `footer` and would display the footer as inline element (on most sites that would cause a mess).  (http://caniuse.com/#search=footer)

This code block is from [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) a often used CSS stylesheet to "normalize" the display of elements across browsers:

```
/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11 and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}
```

The comments are pointing out why they are applying `display: block`.

In some cases, `display: block` may be used to set properties previously changed in CSS. For instance if a plugin wants to make sure its headings are displayed as block, it sets `h1`, `h2`... to `display: block`, because maybe the site it's included in has set `h1` to `inline`.

Comment: +1 great answer. May I suggest also folding in the CSS override possibility as mentioned by evan and pwdst in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

That's done to help older browsers properly display modern HTML. In the case of ul, li, h1 etc. tags that have been around since HTML 1.0, it's overkill. `display: block` is usually done so that modern HTML tags, i.e. HTML 5, that are new such as `canvas`, `article` etc. can be displayed by older, or non-standards browsers.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, depending on context, it may be to restore properties previously changed in CSS. The default value can be used to negate/override a prior property value that is no longer applicable.